# How to interpret NetworkReachabilityFlags in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, reachability

I'm using `NetworkReachability` to figure out the connectivity status of my app:

```
NetworkReachability(this.currentHostUrl);
remoteHostReachability.SetNotification(this.ReachabilityChanged);
remoteHostReachability.Schedule(CFRunLoop.Current, CFRunLoop.ModeDefault);
```

The callback method looks like this:

```
void ReachabilityChanged(NetworkReachabilityFlags flags)
{
    this.reachable = (flags & NetworkReachabilityFlags.Reachable) > 0;
    UIHelpers.GetAppDelegate().UpdateConnectivityToast(this.reachable);
}
```

Now **if I switch to airplane mode**, the callback gets called immediately and the flags parameter is 0. Then, shortly after it triggers again and the flags are

```
ConnectionRequired|IsWWAN|Reachable|TransientConnection
```

If I **turn airplane mode off**, I get another 0 and then afterwards

```
Reachable
```

If I **turn WiFi off and 3G kicks in**, the result is:

```
IsWWAN|Reachable|TransientConnection
```

It seems like checking for `Reachable` alone is not enough. But what's the logic here? What do `ConnectionRequired` and `TransientConnection` mean?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the documentations:

> `ConnectionRequired`: Reachable, but a connection must first be
>   established.
>
> `TransientConnection`: The host is reachable using a transient
>   connection (PPP for example).

[Xamarin API Doc](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3ASystemConfiguration.NetworkReachabilityFlags) and [iOS Lib Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SCNetworkReachabilityFlags)

But you probably can do it like the following sample code:

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/ReachabilitySample/reachability.cs

It basically checks if `Reachable && (!ConnectionRequired || IsWWAN)`.

Comment: documentation about systemconfiguration in xamarin seems to have vanished

Comment: They changed the address of the documentation. I updated the links.

Comment: Documentation link does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If there is ConnectionRequired present, then there is actually no connectivity, even though Reachable is present
so it's something like

```
bool connectionAvailable = (flags.HasFlag(Reachable) && !flags.HasFlags(ConnectionRequired))
```