# Xamarin NetworkReachability reports reachability incorrectly

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Calling 'GetFlags' on NetworkReachability always returns 'Reachable' even if
the domain doesn't exist. I'll attach a full test solution but the following
code should result in "Failed..." but results in "Success = True".

The code is based on the Reachability sample.

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        string host = "http://nonsense.test12345679.com"; 

        using (var r = new SystemConfiguration.NetworkReachability (host)) {
            NetworkReachabilityFlags flags;

            if (r.TryGetFlags (out flags)) {
                _label.Text = "Success = " + IsReachableWithoutRequiringConnection (flags);
            } else {
                _label.Text = "Failed to get flags ";
            }

        }
    }

    public bool IsReachableWithoutRequiringConnection(NetworkReachabilityFlags flags)
    {
        // Is it reachable with the current network configuration?
        bool isReachable = (flags & NetworkReachabilityFlags.Reachable) != 0;

        // Do we need a connection to reach it?
        bool noConnectionRequired = (flags & NetworkReachabilityFlags.ConnectionRequired) == 0
            || (flags & NetworkReachabilityFlags.IsWWAN) != 0;

        return isReachable && noConnectionRequired;
    }
```

If you switch the device into airplane mode then reachability is correctly
returned as false.

I'm testing on an iPad Air, iOS 9.0.2 and the latest stable Xamarin.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used that functionality directly; but have you tried the nuget package for connectivity? https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Connectivity. I have tried it and it seems to work pretty well. It has methods for testing if a specific endpoint is reachable.

```cs
bool canConnect = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected
    && await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable(host, portInt));
```

Comment: Looks like it uses the same Reachability class with some additional socket tests in the Connectivity class https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Connectivity/Connectivity/Connectivity.Plugin.iOS. Can you use the plugins without Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Yes. Some plugins are for specifically for Xamarin.Forms and others can be used in any Xamarin app.

Answer (score 4):

iOS System Configuration framework's [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName) does *not* actually check to see if the host is alive (i.e. it is not a ping/icmp/http/... based test).

> A remote host is considered reachable **when a data packet, sent by an**
> **application into the network stack, can leave the local device.**
> Reachability does not guarantee that the data packet will actually be
> received by the host.

[iOS SCNetworkReachability Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007260)

Also a good SO A/Q on about the Reachability flags : [How to interpret NetworkReachabilityFlags in Xamarin.iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938310/how-to-interpret-networkreachabilityflags-in-xamarin-ios)

Comment: I'm not using SCNetworkReachability. I'm basing my implementation on sample Xamarin code that interprates the flags correctly. https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/ReachabilitySample/reachability.cs

Comment: ?... SystemConfiguration.NetworkReachability Class is a wrapper for the native iOS class

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I still don't believe my example should result in 'Reachable' as the data packet shouldn't be able to leave the device.